I'm trying to create aliases for axis measures in Tableau that are integers. Please advise
I'm wanting to create an axis for a set of Tableau views which measure a period spanning a year, and to avoid confusion, I want them to cover both years rather than just the integer representing a "year"--I cannot do this with dates either, as there is a component involving trend lines, so every column and row involved has to be an integer under the hood.
Essentially, it looks like this:
A horizontal axis showing the years 2015 to 2027
And I'm trying to get it to look like this:
A horizontal axis showing the years 2015-2016 to 2026-2027
So far, I've tried redefining the data types, but that blocks me from being able to maintain the trend lines. Is there any way to accomplish this while still keeping the identity of the rows as integers?

Please edit title with a smaller and clear one.

This solution is a little hacky, but since they are integers, you can just take your current year and your current year plus one, convert them to strings then display them on your axis. As long as you drive the display of the strings off of your original integers, your trends should stay the same.
Create a calculated field name it [axis_labels]:
IF [year] = [year] THEN
STR([year]) + '-' + STR([year]+1)
END

Does work without the IF statement.

What purpose does the IF statement serve? I think you can just keep the part between THEN and END

@AlexBlakemore You are correct, and I edited to that solution, then discarded that edit at the time I posted. I have had issues when it comes to actions/ dashboard filters in displaying data (specifically on an axis) that was not on the original sheet, old habit for redundancy.

I trust Tableau because I know how it works, I just don't trust myself to not make a mistake.

STR([year]) + '-' + STR([year]+1)

Place this calculated field in x-axis.
